# Bags and non-standard evaluation

Tags: evaluation, undocumented

What can internally be happening here? Is the evaluator just messing with us and going non-standard because it's a `Bag`? Or am I just not seeing how something like this could be done in *Mathematica*?

```
AppendTo[$ContextPath, "Internal`"];

In[19]:= ClearAll[x, y];
{x, y} = {Bag[{1, 2, 3}], Bag[{4, 5}]};
```

Heads are

```
In[21]:= Head /@ {x, y}

Out[21]= {Bag, Bag}
```

But they are just a head, no depth. Depths

```
In[22]:= Depth /@ {x, y}

Out[22]= {1, 1}
```

However, they are different. I take their second elements, or I print them in `InputForm`

```
In[23]:= BagPart[#, 2] & /@ {x, y}
InputForm /@ {x, y}

Out[23]= {2, 5}

Out[24]= {InputForm[Internal`Bag[{1, 2, 3}]], InputForm[Internal`Bag[{4, 5}]]}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is not related to evaluation. `` Internal`Bag ``, like many other special types, is an atomic object.  You can verify this using `AtomQ[x]`.  This is despite its `InputForm` suggesting a structure.

This is no different from how `Graph`, `Rational`, `Complex` or `SparseArray` behave.  (Though for `SparseArray`, most list manipulation functions are implemented, so it's much more difficult to notice that it is atomic).

---

A similar example using `Rational`:

```
In[206]:= rats={1/2,2/3}
Out[206]= {1/2,2/3}

In[208]:= Head/@rats
Out[208]= {Rational,Rational}

In[209]:= Depth/@rats
Out[209]= {1,1}

In[210]:= FullForm[rats]
Out[210]//FullForm= List[Rational[1,2],Rational[2,3]]
```

Comment: I am starting to hate to vote for your answers because I will never catch up, but their quality compels me. +1 *yet again*

Comment: I would make a distinction between `Graphs` and other objects. For most atomic objects in the past, it was possible to deconstruct and reconstruct them by using their `InputForm` (`FullForm`), the feature which I consider essential. This plays well with immutability. For `Graph`-s, a decision was made to introduce mutable state (properties), and their `InputForm` is deceiving. I dislike this feature, and also think that one should distinguish these two situations. You are certainly well-aware of this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964469/which-objects-are-atomic-in-mathematica

Comment: Actually, I gave the wrong link. This is the one I meant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301833/new-graph-in-mathematica-8-0/4356488#4356488, and also I share the point of @WReach which he expressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363253/object-oriented-mathematica-programming/7379002#7379002

Answer (score 8):

I think `` Internal`Bag `` is a monolithic object which is only constructed using the `Bag[list]` syntax. Note that the same is true for `Graph`:

```
Graph[{1<->2,2<->3}]//Head
(*
==> Graph
*)
Graph[{1<->2,2<->3}]//Depth
(*
==> 1
*)
```

Also note the output of the objects when typing directly in the kernel:

```
Internal`Bag[{2,3}]
(*
==> Internal`Bag[<2>]
*)
Graph[{1<->2,2<->3}]
(*
==> Graph[<3>, <2>]
*)
```

Even `FullForm` doesn't give more information, which shows that on the Mathematica expression level that's all there is.

Comment: It is not that surprising that `FullForm` is broken with `Bag` since `Bag` is not really meant for user consumption..

Comment: @Szabolcs: But `Graph` is definitely meant for user consumption, and it shows exactly the same behaviour.

Comment: Regarding `Graphs`, see my comment below @Szabolcs's answer.

Comment: Of course, I just meant that the edges are not as polished as for the other types, e.g. `FullForm` on `Graph` does work even though it's atomic (but pattern matching doesn't --- while it works for older types like `Rational`)

Comment: Maybe it's a version thing; as I've shown in my post, `Graph` for me shows the exact same behaviour for `FullForm` as `Bag` (parameters showing up as `<n>`).